# Window close event

Tags: vimscript

For my vim plugin I try to catch an event when quickfix window is closed. I did it with BufWinLeave event. But it does not work when I have quickfix open on multiple tabs, because of 'Not when it's still visible in another window.' from BufWinLeave documentations. But I did not find any other event, that can tell me that some random window is closed. Do you such event or how to do that?

Comment: Why do you have the same quickfix buffer open in multiple windows?  You can use loclists instead of quickfix lists if you need multiple windows.

Comment: It it not my plugin exactly that loads results to a window, my plugin is related to the window control (open, close) and it happens that the quickfix window is open in different tabs, where I need an event that a window is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[vim v8.2.3591](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/23beefed73aadb243fb67cf944e3d60fe8c038bb) added a WinClosed event.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, Thanks, I see the first answers queue is well-manned!